# Find minimum value and replace by the average of previous and next observation in selected data

Tags: loops, dplyr, replace

I have a data frame called nh4.df in R. One of the columns is “Date”. I have more than 900 dates and several observations for each day. I want to select some of these dates, say, “2020-12-03” and “2021-02-05”, and find the minimum value of another column, called “Actual”, and replace these minimum values of these selected dates in nh4.df for the average of the previous and the next observation of Actual values.

Here is a sample example:

```
Date <- c("2020-12-03", "2020-12-03", "2020-12-03", "2021-01-01", "2021-01-01", "2021-01-01", "2021-02-02", "2021-02-02", "2021-02-02", "2021-02-05", "2021-02-05", "2021-02-05")

Actual <- c(10, 1, 11, 12, 13, 14, 10, 11, 10, 17, 2, 18)

nh4.df <- data.frame(Date, Actual)
```

| Date | Actual |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-12-03 | 10 |
| 2020-12-03 | 1 |
| 2020-12-03 | 11 |
| 2021-01-01 | 12 |
| 2021-01-01 | 13 |
| 2021-01-01 | 14 |
| 2021-02-02 | 10 |
| 2021-02-02 | 11 |
| 2021-02-02 | 10 |
| 2021-02-05 | 17 |
| 2021-02-05 | 2 |
| 2021-02-05 | 18 |

In this sample example, I would find the selected days, which are “2020-12-03” and “2021-02-05”. Then, I would replace their mininum values in column Actual by the average of the previous and next observation. That is, I would replace value 1 in column Actual by `(10+11)/2` = 10.5 and I would replace 2 by `(17+18)/2` = 17.5

How can I do that for a large dataset in an optimized way? Thank you.

I tried to do that using loop and also dplyr but was not successful.

data:

```
structure(list(Date = c("2020-12-03", "2020-12-03", "2020-12-03", 
"2021-01-01", "2021-01-01", "2021-01-01", "2021-02-02", "2021-02-02", 
"2021-02-02", "2021-02-05", "2021-02-05", "2021-02-05"), Actual = c(10L, 
1L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 10L, 11L, 10L, 17L, 2L, 18L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dplyr`’s `lag()` and `lead()` together with some grouping can accomplish
this:

1. First we filter down to the selected dates.
2. `group_by()` `Date`, prepare the lag and lead values, and mark the rows
   with the minimum value for Actual.
3. Use `rowwise()` to assign each row its own group, calculate the mean of
   lag and lead and insert the result into Actual where the minimum values are.

```r
library(tidyverse)

selected_dates <-
  c("2020-12-03", "2021-02-05")

df |>
  filter(Date %in% selected_dates) |>
  group_by(Date) |>
  mutate(
    lag = lag(Actual),
    lead = lead(Actual),
    min = Actual == min(Actual)
  ) |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(
    mean_lag_lead = mean(c(lag, lead), na.rm = TRUE),
    Actual = ifelse(min, mean_lag_lead, Actual)
  )
#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#> # Rowwise:  Date
#>   Date       Actual   lag  lead min   mean_lag_lead
#>   <chr>       <dbl> <int> <int> <lgl>         <dbl>
#> 1 2020-12-03   10      NA     1 FALSE           1  
#> 2 2020-12-03   10.5    10    11 TRUE           10.5
#> 3 2020-12-03   11       1    NA FALSE           1  
#> 4 2021-02-05   17      NA     2 FALSE           2  
#> 5 2021-02-05   17.5    17    18 TRUE           17.5
#> 6 2021-02-05   18       2    NA FALSE           2
```